# Remover conjunto específico do final do array com regex

Tags: python, regex

**OBJETIVO**

Estou tentando remover de todos os elementos do array o conteúdo `":PM"` com regex, porém está me retornando erro.

**DETALHES**

O array sempre irá conter ":PM", e é somente essa parte que desejo remover dos elementos do array.

**SCRIPT**

```
import re

array = ['SOLDADO1:PM','SOLDADO2','SOLDADO3:PM','SOLDADO4','SOLDADO5:PM']

regex = r"^...-(.*)"
re.match(regex, array)

for linha in array:
    print(linha)
```

**OUTPUT**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "regex.py", line 6, in
>   
>       re.match(regex, array)   File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 141, in match
>       return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string) TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se o trecho `":PM"` está sempre no final da string, basta fazer:

```
import re

array = ['SOLDADO1:PM','SOLDADO2','SOLDADO3:PM','SOLDADO4','SOLDADO5:PM']
regex = re.compile(r':PM$')
for texto in array:
    print(regex.sub('', texto))
```

Eu uso o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$` para indicar o final da string.

Depois, para cada elemento do array, uso o [método `sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.sub) para substituir o trecho correspondente pela string vazia (`''`), que é o mesmo que remover o trecho.

Saída:

```
SOLDADO1
SOLDADO2
SOLDADO3
SOLDADO4
SOLDADO5
```

---

Se quiser gerar **outra** lista com as strings sem o trecho, basta fazer:

```
outra_lista = [ regex.sub('', texto) for texto in array ]
```

O resultado é a lista `['SOLDADO1', 'SOLDADO2', 'SOLDADO3', 'SOLDADO4', 'SOLDADO5']`.

---

Sobre a sua regex: `^...-(.*)`, ela não funcionou porque ela tem o seguinte:

- `^`: marcador de início da string
- `...-`: 3 caracteres seguido de hífen
- `(.*)`: zero ou mais caracteres

Ou seja, bem longe de ser o que você precisa. Além disso, o [método `match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) recebe uma string, não uma lista. Por isso fazemos o *loop* e aplicamos a regex para cada elemento da lista.

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado, ficou perfeita sua didática, parabéns!

Answer (score 2):

Sei que a outra resposta já foi aceita, mas acho que vale a pena acrescentar para quem estiver lendo essa pergunta no futuro:

Não use regexp para isso, a operação nesse caso é simples demais para valer a pena usar regexp; Você terá um código mais simples e que funciona melhor usando o método `endswith` e fatiando a string:

```
outra_lista = [texto[:-3] if texto.endswith(':PM') else texto for texto in array]
```